# How to concat output to existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a typical dataframe df

I am trying to add sklearn's output to dataframe:

code:

```
rc_g_oo = RandomForestClassifier()
rc_g_oo.fit(X_oo, y_oo)
pred_oo_p = rc_g_oo.predict_proba(df_test)

print("Predicting probability of class")
pred_oo_p = rc_g_oo.predict_proba(df_test)

probability:  [[0.33 0.67]
 [0.59 0.41]
 [0.39 0.61]
 ...
 [0.69 0.31]
 [0.57 0.43]
 [0.55 0.45]]
```

And finally I would like to be it in a dataframe:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'predicted_1': pred_h,
    'predicted_1': pred_a,
    'predicted_probability': pred_oo_p,
})
```

However I get a multi- dimensional error. I will edit the question with the error once I can reproduce it.

Comment: Is it `probability` an array? do you want to add 2 more columns or add them in existing columns? What did you try?

Comment: can you please post your expected output?

Comment: @Joe I tried exactly this `concat = [df_historical, result]
df_historical_archive = pd.concat(concat)` And I got a dimensional error. The number of rows are the same as the dataframe 'result'

Comment: Yes Anurag, I would If I could completing this code, its taking a lot of time to run lol

Comment: Also pls post your df along with expected output ...you only posted probability array in your question

Comment: Updated code. Will post error when I have it

Answer (score 0):

Your probability is not  a comma separated list. It looks like you're intentionally outputting each value and appending it without appending after a full iteration. You need to work around that before you add it into a dictionary.

Comment: How do I convert list to dataframe?

Comment: ```import pandas as pd 
your_list = ['item0', 'item'1, 'item2',...]
df =pd.DataFrame (your_list,columns=['Column_Name_of _your_choice'])```

Comment: Would one column name suffice for `[[0.33 0.67]
 [0.59 0.41]]` ? I would try `list = probability:  [[0.33 0.67]
 [0.59 0.41] df = pd.DataFrame(probability, columns = ['new col1'])`  Would that be the right way?

Comment: Those values in the probability list are not comma separated which denies the list functionality. Maybe I would like to see the code the produced them.